# How to bind a property of one element to a property of another in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

The following is some partial XAML:

```
<CheckBox Content="Display Data Points?" Margin="8,0.04,0,4" Grid.Row="1" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

and

```
<vf:DataSeries RenderAs="Line" DataSource="{Binding CdTeRoughnessList}" XValueType="DateTime" MarkerEnabled="{Binding ???}" Color="Red" LegendText="Roughness Average">
```

I would like to bind the **MarkerEnabled** property of the DataSeries to the **IsChecked** property of the CheckBox. In other words, when the user checks the check box, I want the MarkerEnabled to be set to True and False when unchecked.

Can this be done (I'm almost sure WPF would support this)? If so, how might I do it?

Comment: [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx)?

Comment: Name the CheckBox and refer to it via ElelmentName like H.B. said with the Path = IsChecked.  You may need to use a converted as IsChecked might be bool?.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Give your Checkbox a name and then bind appropriately:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="DisplayDataCheckbox" Content="Display Data Points?"/>

<vf:DataSeries MarkerEnabled="{Binding ElementName=DisplayDataCheckbox, Path=IsChecked}">
```

Comment: What if I just want to set MarkedEnabled once, copying IsChecked's value in the .xaml?